# Setup Project add behavior logic depending on user registration dialog

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, installation, windows-forms-designer

I want to create a .NET Setup Project with additional dialog (User registration). But in that dialog user can either register straight away or choose to register later. In my case I want to restrict further installation until user is registered. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance :D

UPD:

I my program, the user registration is checking with the server, does the user have right to install it. If yes, then the program installs (unzips) some additional components (database engine components) and inserts necessary records into it. But, in case user clicks "NEXT" button in the wizard (which means user wants to register later), in that case I want to terminate the installation or simply refuse clicking "NEXT"  option.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ".NET Setup Project" is a Visual Studio Setup Project that builds an MSI file then you can't do this. All custom actions run at the end of the install after everything has been installed. You can't add custom dialogs like this at the start of the install. If you're not using a Visual Studio Setup Project then every dialog of this kind that I've seen simply disables the Next button so the user cannot progress without registering. If you are using a Visual Studio Setup Project then disable the Next button in your custom action code and throw an InstallException if you want to rollback the install - there's no way to have your code run before the install to prevent it proceeding. It's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supply much information concerning your program as a whole, but if the installer is setup ***with*** the registration, the issue standing is dissolved. For starters, just make the main thread launch your registration form first, and if a user fails to register or chooses not to do so, exit the program and leave it at that; you can add a dialog specifying why the user cannot install your program as well. If registered successfully, try a login and or continue to the installation process.